# Use Single Quote instead of colons in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get this test to pass:

```
 it "returns an object with the correct fields" do 
      expected_response = {"animal_time": @curr_time.strftime("%F %T"), "animals":{}}
      expect(AnimalHaircutSession.latest_for(@animal_haircut)).to eq(expected_response)
  end
```

When running the test I get this error:

```
 expected: {:animal_time=>"2020-02-14 09:48:30", :animals=>{}}
 got: {"animal_time"=>"2020-02-14 16:48:30", "animals"=>{}}
```

Why is it converting my expected response to colons and how can I set my expected response to use single quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby colons are used to define hashes with symbols for keys . The keys will be cast into symbols.

```
{ "foo": "bar" } == { :foo => "bar" } # true
{ "foo": "bar" } != { "foo" => "bar" } # true
```

If you want to define a hash where the keys are not symbols use hash-rockets (`=>`).

```
it "returns an object with the correct fields" do 
  expected_response = {
    "animal_time" => @curr_time.strftime("%F %T"), 
    "animals" => {}
  }
  expect(AnimalHaircutSession.latest_for(@animal_haircut)).to eq(expected_response)
end
```

While Ruby will allow you to mix hash-rockets and colons in a hash it's generally not considered good form.

Comment: this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `{ foo: => "bar" }` be either `{ foo: "bar" }` or `{ :foo => "bar" }`?

Comment: Your absolutely correct @3limin4t0r, thanks for finding that typo.

Comment: Rails has some code that makes grabbing keys in either form transparent, I consider it pretty bad to not know what's in the hash since we're supposed to be in control of the data, not it in control of us or the code.

Comment: I was _TRYING_ to keep that from being mentioned. :-) It's like Cthulu and Voldemort, we shouldn't mention their nam... oh. Nevermind. I definitely agree about learning Ruby first. People jump into Rails and get swamped. It's a hard-enough learning curve by itself.